# JQuery UI tabs: inactive tab's text shown only on hover

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Could someone suggest a recipe for showing inactive tab's text only on hover?
I usually use an icon + text for a tab like below:

```
<a href="#myLeaves"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span>Leaves</a></li>
```

so that inactive tab shows only the icon while text is shown on hover

Comment: I will mark both answers as useful and maybe wait for some more community feedback; javascript solution could be handy for adding an effect of sliding the label out of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the text in a span then you can handle this with single CSS declaration.
For example if you wrapped the span with a class `.tab-title` then:

```
.ui-tab:not(.ui-state-active):not(:hover) .tab-title {
  display: none; /*or opacity: 0; and animate away */
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

```css
.ui-tab:not(.ui-state-active):not(:hover) .tab-title {
  display: none;
  /*or opacity: 0; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span><span class="tab-title">Nunc tincidunt</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flag"></span><span class="tab-title">Proin dolor</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span><span class="tab-title">Aenean lacinia</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper
      leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum.
      Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean
      aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat.
      Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
      nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna
      ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum.
      Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: snippet: second tab is not possible to activate while third tab is showing the label for me all the time (@Chrome)

Comment: @Kodak what do you mean by *activate*? ... oh wait... damn I thought you want to hide text of *disabled* tabs so I disabled second tab for example on purpose :p

Comment: works exactly as expected and being pure CSS solution is also nice :)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your text with a `label` item and initially hide it via CSS.

Then, bind a [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function on your menu items that shows the `label` when the mouse pointer enters, and hides it when the mouse pointer leaves:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu a").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("label").show();
  }, function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).find("label").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu a:not(.active) label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#home" class="active"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span><label>home</label></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#flag"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flag"></span><label>flag</label></a>
  </li>
  <a href="#search"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span><label>search</label></a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: what about active tab? I would like it to have the label visible from the start

Comment: thx, it probably works as expected; just the snippet is not as good as in TJ's answer

Answer (score 0):

As for the sliding out of view, I'd use a flexible width with `overflow: hidden` like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 28px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
a > label {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
a > span.ui-icon {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0;
  left: 2px;
}

a:hover > label, a.active > label {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<a class="active" href="#myLeaves"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span><label>Leaves</label></a>
<a href="#flag"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flag"></span><label>long label</label></a>
<a href="#search"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search"></span><label>another long label</label></a>
```

I used fixed-size tabs here but you can easily change it to be flexible using percent values.

Comment: active tab should have its label displayed at all time like it T J's answer

Comment: updated. anchor with class "active" now has its label always shown.

Comment: can you please update snippet to use flexible tabs? general idea is to save space when having too many tabs

Comment: updated again for flexible tabs. I cant get the anchor block to animate though.